# GameCenter (Achievements) After Launching in App store?

Tags: ios, game-center

Trying to get something out the door but want to make sure that if GameCenter is a V2 feature that we can add it in after the game is already out and in the App Store.  Can that be done and pushed as an updated version of the game app without forcing people to discover and download a totally new app?

Having a hard time finding answers for this, just want to make sure that this is something we can hold off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can add achievements in the same app for its next version. Not a problem at all. Your user will get notification that update is available once they updated they will have feature. No need to make separate app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's possible to add features like Game Center, in-app purchase, and push notifications with a future update.